# Magento: one product multiple warehouse

Tags: magento

I have two warehouses one for US and other one for Europe. I have two store views one for US and one for Europe. I have one product with same sku but different stock values for US and Europe. I can sell product to US from US warehouse and to Europe from Europe warehouse only. The problem is if I have product "in stock" in Europe warehouse but "out of stock" for US warehouse it still shows that product is "in stock" for US store view. How can I separate warehouses for US and Europe store view?

Comment: From what I remember you can't using purely Magento Community core code. I think this might be one of the features of Enterprise, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @Cags: maybe you have an idea what file I need to change in order for me to influence the link between store view and warehouse?

Comment: You say you have two warehouses, what exactly do you mean by this, because I didn't think there was any support for this in core.

Comment: @Cags: I mean that I have two different warehouses with thier own values of the product and for each product in Admin->ERP I can see quantity of the product available in each warehouse but not in the Frontend :S

Comment: I think if you want a clear answer you will need to provide more details. To my knowledge there is no such thing as Admin ERP in Magento Community.

Comment: Neither CE or EE provide multiple stock locations. There is some code in the core that hints towards adding this in the future but there's nothing yet.

Comment: are you using the embedded ERP extension by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box in Magento CE or EE you can't. There is no support for multi-warehouse (multiple inventories).

You can look at modules that can do multi-location: [Embedded ERP](http://www.boostmyshop.com/english/extension-logistique.html) (and you can do more research yourself to find other providers).

Usually, if you have this kind of complexity, the stock is managed by the ERP system.